# Unable to retrieve metadata for MVCMusicStore.Model.Album while creating Controller with read/write actions and views, using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I follow this tutorial and I have made exacly step by step what author said form the part 1. The only difference is that my Solution is **MVC 4** and tutorial is for **MVC 3**.

Tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5

When I want to do the first thing: Creating the StoreManagerController my menu looks little bit different.

**My menu looks like(I showed all the options I can choose from):**

[image]

**In tutorial it looks like:**

[image]

**When I click Add button I get:**

[image]

**Problem:** I have no idea how to deal with that. Should I choose different template?

**Link to project(works fine)** I have done everything till beginning of Part 5: http://www.speedyshare.com/RGdqH/MvcMusicStore.zip

**Context class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models {
    public class MusicStoreEntities: DbContext {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

In **Web.config** file I had originally:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMusicStore-20140621145633;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMusicStore-20140621145633.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

but author said that there suppose to be:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.sdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

so I commented old one and put the one from tutorial and my **Web.config** looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
<!--  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMusicStore-20140621145633;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMusicStore-20140621145633.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>-->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.sdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>  
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**What then should I have there?**

EDIT3:

When I changed from `providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"` to `Name="System.Data.SqlClient"` when I run the solution link `http://localhost:6468/store/` stopped working. Before change it displayed all the genres in the store. Like this: 
[image] after the change I get this:

[image]

Comment: That error is pretty informative , can you post your Context class? I think you just selected the wrong option in the dropdown for "Data Context Class"

Comment: @ScottSelby I posted this class at the bottom of OP. Thank you for your time. I have hope I understood you correctly, this is my first ASP.NET project.

Comment: just try to delete that controller , Clean - Build - Run the project, then try to add the controller again

Comment: @ScottSelby The controller has not been added -> I couldn't delete it. I Clean - Build - Run then stop project then tried to create `StoreManagerController` again and again got the same error message, but much faster.

Comment: @ScottSelby Could you have a glance at Melvinr answer and look at the EDIT2, please.

Comment: @Yoda in your solution explorer, click the `Show All Files` button and then see if you have a db file in your `App_Data` folder.

Comment: @SOfanatic I have 2 files `MvcMusicStore.Models.MusicStoreEntities.mdf` and `MvcMusicStore.sdf. Uncommenting orignal(see EDIT2) connection strings and commenting the one provided by author enabled creating `StoreManagerController`. Is leaving `name = "DefaultConnection` is wrong and should I delete `StoreManagerController` if I will want to change it?

Comment: @ScottSelby Changed it in EDIT3. Please look.

Answer (score 1):

Your DefaultConecction string should have and incorrect provider, use System.Data.SqlClient

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="...." />
```

**EDIT:**

As you want to use a custom connection string you have to specify it on your  MusicStoreEntities class constructor

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models {
    public class MusicStoreEntities: DbContext {
        public MusicStoreEntities() : base("MusicStoreEntities")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh that's good one! please look at the OP in 2 minutes I am making edit.

Comment: Please look at the EDIT2.

Comment: You also need to specify your connection. 
public MusicStoreEntities() : base("MusicStoreEntities"){ }

Comment: Please elaborate on that in your answer, I am ASP.NET total noob: I did little bit of WP8 and WPF and Forms in past. Uncommenting old connetcion string and commenting the one that author provided solved problem.

Comment: leave it exactly like the tutorial told you to do it , but replace and make it like this in the uncommented on the tutorial told you to add  -- providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: @Melvinr Changing providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" made the website throw exception. I'll 1 minute please.  http://s22.postimg.org/mwc0mkp0h/image.png

Comment: @Melvinr The author wanted to use Compact Edition of MS SQL. Uncommenting original didn't make website not wokring, chaning providerName gave this: http://s22.postimg.org/mwc0mkp0h/image.png

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand that language at all :S

Comment: @Melvinr Could you download the project. Link is in the OP: http://www.speedyshare.com/RGdqH/MvcMusicStore.zip It is before creating this StoreManagerControler -> it is clean and working just before beginning of PART 5 of tutorial

Comment: @Melvinr Explanation: When I changed from `providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"` to `Name="System.Data.SqlClient"` when I run the solution link `http://localhost:6468/store/` stopped working. Before change it displayed all the genres in the store. Like this: http://s29.postimg.org/j0t51qst3/image.png after the change I get this: http://s22.postimg.org/mwc0mkp0h/image.png

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the connection strings form your web.config file and save it. 
Then create the controller as explained in the tutorial. 
Then paste the connections strings back in web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the connection strings form your web.config file hit save. Then create the controller. Hit undo in the web.config file and then save again

Answer (score 0):

To help others and because I was stuck on this for HOURS, adding

```
 public DbSet<Artist> Artists{ get; set; }
```

to the music store entities file should fix the problem